# Add Delay to For Loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, bind, delay

I tried the solution found here: [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop) but I could not make it work for me.

```
    jQuery.fn.createEntry = function () {
        $("#List").append('<span>New Entry</span>');
        $("#List span").draggable({ grid: [30,45] });
    }

    jQuery.fn.tenTimes = function() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
            $(document).createEntry();
        }
    }
```

In the .createEntry() script, the new object is binded to a .draggable() plugin I have. I'm using a keyboard shortcut (keyup) to run this tenTimes function(). If I press the key more than once too quickly, many of the new objects won't be draggable. It's seemingly random which objects fail to become draggable. I thought perhaps my rapid keypresses disrupt the bind event for the ones that fail, but even if I go slow, some don't become draggable.

Is there some way I could check to see if the object was binded properly, before moving on with the for loop? Is there a strictly better approach? Unfortunately, this isn't an animation, so I can't use .delay().

*SOLUTION*

It was a 3rd script I had going that handled the elements using appendTo() to that was causing the issue.

Using append() or appendTo() seemed to keep the object binded with the draggable, but it loses its left/top css along the way, so it can't be dragged. Rather than figuring out some .css() hack (the values are unique for each), I simply created a brand new element, and copied the relevant data over, then remove() the old one. Draggable is binded to it properly at some other point. With this, the problem is fixed.

Comment: It's likely the problem lies in the createEntry() function.

Comment: @joeframbach - I added the function; its very bare, hence why I omitted it, but it could be syntax that's breaking it.

Comment: How's this going? I'm interested in what the issue was.

Comment: @joeframbach - appendTo() seems to be the problem, the element remains binded to the draggable or something; in either case, if I simply create a brand new img element, and copy the relevant data over, I get no issues.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Try .setTimeout()

I did not read that you said .Delay() can not be used.

Comment: Try reading the question again. *"Unfortunately, this isn't an animation, so I can't use .delay()."*

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you may find a slight performance benefit by replacing

```
jQuery.fn.createEntry = function () {
    $("#List").append('<span>New Entry</span>');
    $("#List span").draggable({ grid: [30,45] });
}
```

with

```
jQuery.fn.createEntry = function () {
    $("#List").append($('<span>New Entry</span>').draggable({ grid: [30,45] }));
}
```

Because you probably don't want to reapply `draggable` to all of your already-existing `span`s.

Actually, that's probably what's breaking your code. The first `span` has `draggable` reapplied to it 10 times. Is `draggable` idempotent?